# How to use an image as title using MLT/melt video editing tool?

Tags: macos, command-line, video-editing

I'm just beginning to use the MLT/melt command-line tool to edit some pretty simple videos. I found how to join several video clips, how to set a fade transition between the different clips, the only thing I'd need and can't manage is inserting a title at the very beginning of my movies.

I thought of creating a `.jpg` or `.png` image, then add to the melt arguments (I think I saw one or two examples around here), but it looks like melt doesn't behave as expected.

1. It was not accepting my 16-bit `.png`. Well, no problem, I used an 8-bit `.png` and it worked.
2. I can't get the image to be displayed long enough. No matter which `in` and `out` values I set, the image briefly appears and disappears. Here's the command line I'm currently using:

   `melt title-8.png in=0 out=300 clip-1.mp4 -consumer avformat:... vcodec=.. acodec=...`

*Mac OS 10.9.1, Melt 0.9.0*

*Edit : Just tried the same command on a Linux VM, and it seem to work as intended with Melt 0.8.8. Maybe a bug or a new behaviour introduced by the 0.9 version, I'll check that out.*

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Comment: You're right, I didn't include the OS because I think MLT's only available on *nix systems. I've just edited my question and added the OS I use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the length of the image producer:

```
melt title-8.png length=300 in=0 out=299 clip-1.mp4
```

Also, in/out points are zero based. So to show 300 frames, out needs to be 299.